# Set modal window width more than outlook add-in width

Tags: modal-dialog, popup, width, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I need to make a popup or modal window in a outlook add-in which the width of the popup or modal is greater than outlook add-in width.

I tried several methods. but they only allow the popup/modal within outlook add-in boundaries.  How to increase its width more than boundaries and move it through browser window. I am using React and .NET

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating display dialog using displayDialogAsync API and give custom width and height.

> Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://www.contoso.com/myDialog.html', {height: 30, width: 20});

For more details on how to create a display dialog please refer [Use the Office dialog API in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)